# /dev/sda2: recovering journal after kubuntu screen

Tags: boot

I had Ubuntu running and wanted to see how KDE looks like. So I installed it, didn't like it and decided to uninstall it again. Now however, my boot hangs at:

```
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean 416232/6782976 files, 11657744/27123456 blocks
```

After 240 seconds, this appears:

```
[  240...] INFO: task mtp-probe:258 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  240...]       Not tainted 4.4.0-22-generic #40 Ubuntu
[  240...] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

and than every other 120s

```
[  360...] INFO: task mtp-probe:258 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[  360...]       Not tainted 4.4.0-22-generic #40 Ubuntu
[  360...] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

I can handle the terminal.

Some more info:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
├─sda1 vfat         B6D4-538C                            /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4         43b61b47-3654-3e62-a059-06f53eb4d03c /
└─sda3 swap         91731bfc-13bf-465a-fa81-1f880d10d07a [SWAP]
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that there was an error that I found using `journalctl`:

```
sudo journalctl -u lightdm
```

Something like this

```
lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found out where this file comes using `apt-file`:

```
$ apt-file find pam_kwallet.so 
libpam-kwallet4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_kwallet.so
```

I installed `libpam-kwallet4` using:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-kwallet4
```

This got rid of the error in `journalctl` but lightdm didn't start automatically after booting yet. A

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

solved the issue.